# Excel csv import: Dates are transformed to Int64 - How can I get dates to be formatted as "date"?

Tags: excel, csv, csv-import

- When I load a csv-file to excel via "get data" -> "from file" -> "csv"
- Excel converts my date (05.12.2015) to int64 --> "5122015"

**When I double click on the csv:**

- I get the dates correctly formatted
- but everything else is messed up (e.g. "München" appears as "MÃ¼nchen")
- that is why I need the csv import, but with correct dates

How can I import the csv file correctly but also get the right date format?

**Things I have already tried:**

- Import csv
- Double click on csv file
- import csv with different options (UTF-8, UTF-7, 1252 Western European...)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using either Power Query or the legacy import wizard (which you used) (and using either English or Estonian regional settings). The date data gets interpreted properly.  What are your windows regional settings for short date; date separator; thousands separator; decimal separator?  Did you indicate in the import wizard that the column was a date column, and with the proper component order (DMY or MDY)?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe that import wizard doesn't open with the method you are using. If that's the case, you could change the extension from .csv to .txt; or use Power Query.

Comment: Thank you so far for your responses. 
In the windows Settings the regiaonal format for both are set to DD.MM.YYY, same a s in the .csv file

I will check the import wizard once more.

Comment: You were right. In the Power Query Editor, I can change the columns data type to date, but it doesn't remember that. Everytime I upload the csv, I have to perform the same steps on a couple of columns again, which is a lot of manual work.

Comment: **Refresh** the query instead of starting a new one.